# SumblimeText2 Vintage command repeat

Tags: sublimetext2

How I can bind some command with repeats?

For example: I need to bind a command to move the cursor down to 10 lines.
For one line it's like this:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+j"], "command": "set_motion", "args": {
    "motion": "move",
    "motion_args": {"repeat": 1,"by": "lines", "forward": true, "extend": true },
    "linewise": true },
    "context": [{"key": "setting.command_mode"}]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a plugin:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class CommandWithRepeats(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, repeats, **args): 
        for x in xrange(repeats):
            self.view.run_command(args['command'], args['args'])
```

And then we can add any command in key bindings with repeats:

```
"keys": ["alt+j"],
"command": "command_with_repeats",
"context": [{"key": "setting.command_mode"}],
"args": {
    "repeats": 10,
    "command": "set_motion",
    "args": {
        "motion": "move",
        "motion_args": {
            "by": "lines",
            "forward": true,
            "extend": true
        },
        "linewise": true
    }
}
```

Wrap any command in `command_with_repeats()` and it executes some times (`repeats` arguement)